# Swift writing to contents of textview to RTF file doesn't work XCODE 12.4

Tags: swift

I've been trying all day to write contents of a textview into an already existing RTF file in my project. However, it doesn't work. It compiles successfully but when it's all done running, and I go to the file, nothing I'm writing is in the rtf file. here is the code:

```
if let rtfPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BugReports", withExtension: "rtf") {
                    if let attributedText = reportEntry1.attributedText {
                        let documentAttributes: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf]
                        do {
                            let text2 = try String(contentsOf: rtfPath, encoding: .utf8)
                            print(text2)
                            let rtfData = try attributedText.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length), documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
                            let rtfString = String(data: rtfData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
                            try rtfString.write(to: rtfPath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                        } catch {
                            print("failed to submit a report: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

EDIT, I now know bundles cannot be written to so this is what it is currently, but it still doesn't work.

```
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
                let rtfPath = dir.appendingPathComponent("BugReports.rtf")
                    if let attributedText = reportEntry1.attributedText {
                        let documentAttributes: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf]
                        do {
                            let rtfData = try attributedText.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length), documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
                            let rtfString = String(data: rtfData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
                            try rtfString.write(to: rtfPath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                        } catch {
                            print("failed to submit a reportaaaaaaa: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The bundle directory is read only

Comment: How should I go about retrieving it then

Comment: You mean writing it. You have many options. It all depends if you would like the user to have access to the file or not.

Comment: You should take some time and read [file system basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: What is your question about?  You want to save the UITextView content as RTF or save it as plain string?  Which is it?

Comment: I would like to save the UITextView.text to the existing rtf file

Comment: Check edit on post

Comment: @D.programa you have to read from the bundle, and save to the documents directory